# How do I debug Squeak source code?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

Here is the  division method in Squeak 4.1:

```
/t1
| t2 |
t1 isInteger
    ifTrue: [t2 := self digitDiv: t1 abs neg: self negative ~~ t1 negative.
        (t2 at: 2)
                = 0
            ifTrue: [^ (t2 at: 1) normalize].
        ^ (Fraction numerator: self denominator: t1) reduced].
^ t1 adaptToInteger: self andSend: #/
```

I do not understand the code. Can you give me some hints on how to debug the code, so I can trace the code behavior? Like open a workspace, type 4/3, I can inspect into Fraction. There are objects self, numerator, denominator and etc. How can I step into 4/3, and see how Smalltalk implemented division?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, something is wrong with your sources. The method **Integer>>/** actually looks like this:

```
/ aNumber
"Refer to the comment in Number / "
| quoRem |
aNumber isInteger ifTrue:
    [quoRem := self digitDiv: aNumber abs   "*****I've added abs here*****"
                    neg: self negative ~~ aNumber negative.
    (quoRem at: 2) = 0
        ifTrue: [^ (quoRem at: 1) normalize]
        ifFalse: [^ (Fraction numerator: self denominator: aNumber) reduced]].
^ aNumber adaptToInteger: self andSend: #/
```

Secondly, this code is only used for large integers. If you evaluate `4 / 3` this method is not used, but rather **SmallInteger>>/** which creates a Fraction directly.

To invoke the method you want, you need to use a large number, e.g.:

```
12345678901234567890 / 2
```

Select this expression, and choose "debug it" from the context menu. Alternatively, you can use the "halt" message to invoke the debugger:

```
12345678901234567890 halt / 2
```

When the debugger pops up, click its "Into" button to step into the method.

Comment: Something is wrong with your sources means: the squeak image is capable of decompiling all compiled methods, but doesn't know the names of parameters and variables (and comments) without the SqueakV39.sources file (or a newer version of course) being visible to it. Take a look at a one-click image to see where the sources should be. If the sources cannot be found, t1...tn are used as names.

Comment: the answwer helps me alot, thanks Bert Freudenberg and Stephan Eggermont :)